# Isomorphism theorems proofs question

Tags: group-theory

I've been trying to understand proofs of second and fourth isomorphism theorems and got a confused by seemingly different usage of the inverse of a quotient map.

My first point of confusion. To prove the existance of a bijection needed for correspondence theorem( 4th isomorphism):

> $\phi:  \{\text{subgroups } \text{K} \text{ of }G \text{ containig }H\} \rightarrow \{\text{subgroups of } G / H\} $, $K\mapsto \pi(K) = K/H$.

The inverse function of $\phi$ is defined as follows: $\phi^{-1}(K') = \pi^{-1}(K') = \{g \in G | gH 
 \in K'\}$. I know that $\phi(K) = \pi (K) = \{kH| k \in K\} = K/H$. Could there be some element $a \in A$, $ a \not \in K$, such that $aH = kH$ for some $k \in K$, where $A, K$ are subgroups of $G$. But then the image of $\pi^{-1}(K/H)$ must also have $a$ in it, which says that $(\pi^{-1} \circ \pi)(K) \ne K$ because $a \in im (\pi^{-1} \circ \pi)(K), a \not \in K $. If this is true, then $\phi = \pi$ is not a bijection

Secondly, the part of second isomorphism theorem says that $KH$ is a subgroup if $H$ is normal. The proof that confuses me gets the result in a following way:

> Note that $KH$ is the union of all cosets $kH$, with $k \in K$; that is, 
>   $$KH = (\pi^{-1}\circ \pi)(K)$$

This confused me even more as I encountered the same seemingly different usage of $\pi^{-1}$ in the same source (Algebra: Chapter 0 by P. Aluffi). It seems like $\pi(K) = (KH)/H$ and I don't understand why(actually, elements of both $KH/H$ and $K/H$ may be written in a following way $khH = kH$(which makes them equal, right?), but there's no way $K$ and $KH$ are equal in general). For all I know, $(\pi^{-1}\circ \pi)(K)$ should be equal to $K$, right? Please, help me gain a better understanding of this topic!

Comment: If $a\in A$ and $aH=kH$ then for some $k\in K$ and $h\in H$ $a=kh$. But then $H\subset K$, so $kh\in H$. So $a \in H$. Also, note that $\phi \neq \pi$

Comment: For the second one, I highly suspect it must read $\pi^{-1}(\pi(K))$, first because $\pi$ in general does not have inverse, second because what I've said fits with the preceding description

Comment: It is indeed written $\pi^{-1}(\pi(K))$ and I wrote as a composition because I thought it is the same thing.

Comment: Usually, you only use $\circ$ for composition of functions, so when you write $(f\circ g)^{-1}(A)$ for example, it is pre-image of the function $f\circ g$, which then becomes $g^{-1}(f^{-1}(A))$ (i.e.  function $g$'s pre-image of the set $f^{-1}(A)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: if $aH = kH$ then $ak^{-1} \in H \subseteq K$. This means that $ak^{-1} = k'$ for some $k' \in K$. But then $a = kk' \in K$.

I'm not sure I really understand your second question. By definition, $$\pi(K) = K/H = \{ kH : k \in K\}$$
is a set *whose elements are cosets*. But we want an expression for the set whose elements are *the elements of all these cosets*. And it turns out that $\pi^{-1}$ takes any coset $kH$ and yields the set of all its elements: $\pi^{-1}(kH) = \{ kh : h \in H\}$. So taking the preimage of all the cosets yields all their elements: $$\pi^{-1}(\pi(K)) = \pi^{-1}(K/H) = \bigcup_{kH \in K/H} \pi^{-1}(kH) = \bigcup_{kH \in K/H} \{kh : h \in H\} = \bigcup_{k \in K} \{kh : h \in H\} = KH.$$

Answer (score 1):

*First point:*

It is obvious that $\; K\subset \varphi^{-1}\bigl(\varphi(K)\bigr)\;$ (this has nothing to do with group theory).

Conversely, if $a\in \varphi^{-1}\bigl(\varphi(K)\bigr)\;$, i.e. if $aH=kH$ for some $k\in K$, then in particular $a\in kH\subset K$, so we also have the reverse inclusion.

*Second point:*

If $H$ is normal, for any $g\in G$, we have $gH=Hg$. This is true more specifically for all $k\in K$, so there results that 
$$KH=HK\tag{1}$$
Now we have to prove $(KH)(KH)\subset KH$. This is easy with relation $(1)$ and associativity of multiplication:
$$(KH)(KH)=K(HK)H=K(KH)H=(KK)(HH)=KH.$$